# How do I modify this module class to work with userforms and worksheet objects?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on an Excel doc that is being used by a lot of users, some of which are not tech savy. I came across this code in an effort to enable right click context menus for copy and paste in textboxes. It works PERFECTLY in userforms, however, I have textboxes on my worksheets that need to have the right click context menus as well. Are there any changes that can be made to the classes or to the initialization to allow this code to work on worksheets? Thank you!

Class Module Code:

```
'Popup objects
Private cmdBar As CommandBar
Private WithEvents cmdCopyButton As CommandBarButton
Private WithEvents cmdPasteButton As CommandBarButton

'Useform to use
Private fmUserform As Object


'Control array of textbox
Private colControls As Collection

'Textbox Control
Private WithEvents tbControl As MSForms.TextBox
'Adds all the textbox in the userform to use the popup bar
Sub Initialize(ByVal UF As Object)
   Dim Ctl As MSForms.Control
   Dim cBar As clsBar
   For Each Ctl In UF.Controls
      If TypeName(Ctl) = "TextBox" Then

         'Check if we have initialized the control array
        If colControls Is Nothing Then
            Set colControls = New Collection
            Set fmUserform = UF

            'Create the popup
           CreateBar
         End If

         'Create a new instance of this class for each textbox
        Set cBar = New clsBar
         cBar.AssignControl Ctl, cmdBar
         'Add it to the control array
        colControls.Add cBar
      End If
   Next Ctl
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
   'Delete the commandbar when the class is destroyed
  On Error Resume Next
   cmdBar.Delete
End Sub

'Click event of the copy button
Private Sub cmdCopyButton_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)
   fmUserform.ActiveControl.Copy
   CancelDefault = True
End Sub

'Click event of the paste button
Private Sub cmdPasteButton_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)
   fmUserform.ActiveControl.Paste
   CancelDefault = True
End Sub

'Right click event of each textbox
Private Sub tbControl_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
      ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

   If Button = 2 And Shift = 0 Then
      'Display the popup
     cmdBar.ShowPopup
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub CreateBar()
   Set cmdBar = Application.CommandBars.Add(, msoBarPopup, False, True)
   'We’ll use the builtin Copy and Paste controls
  Set cmdCopyButton = cmdBar.Controls.Add(ID:=19)
   Set cmdPasteButton = cmdBar.Controls.Add(ID:=22)
End Sub

'Assigns the Textbox and the CommandBar to this instance of the class
Sub AssignControl(TB As MSForms.TextBox, Bar As CommandBar)
   Set tbControl = TB
   Set cmdBar = Bar
End Sub
```

Userform Code:

```
 Dim cBar As clsBar

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Set cBar = New clsBar
   cBar.Initialize Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Different from Userform, excel worksheet put those object in `OLEObject collection` not `Controls collection`. Not sure that `MSForms.TextBox` needed to be edited or not.

Comment: Adding ActiveX controls on a worksheet automatically adds a reference to the MSForms type library to your VBA project (as does adding a UserForm to your project), so if your worksheet controls are ActiveX, the code should work pretty much as-is. Making it work with "worksheet form controls" might be impossible though. What have you tried, what's not working, where and how? As it stands, your question is too broad.

Comment: I have added the 'Userform code' to the sheet module under the Private Sub Worksheet_Activate event. I get a runtime 438 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error on the 'cBar.Intialize Me' line. I assume this is due to 'Me' being an parent reference to a userform and not a reference to a sheet. I have attempted replacing 'Me' with 'Activesheet' and a reference straight to the textbox 'sheets("sheet1").textbox1'.